# Develop small shift worker schedule using If, than etc

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, visual-basic

I manage a small team of shift workers, 2 full time and 3 who fill in on shifts that can't be covered.

For a small number of staff I seem to spend a lot of time figuring out schedules (there are lots of rules-union). I want to automate this as much as possible.

I have the two full time persons' schedules automated and have identified the shift I need filled.

What I need is to schedule the other three. They each have to get roughly equal hours of shifts (over 28 days). There are 18 x 8 hour shifts and 4 x 4 hour shifts. There are also event shifts which are 4 hours but change every month - depending on when we are rented.

I want an if/then statement or maybe I need a macro or some VBA code that says *if shift is "open" than schedule person A/B/C* and somehow I need to make sure these hours are even. Any suggestions on how I may achieve this?

Comment: I agree with Paul's response. It's not so much that this can't be done in Excel, more that there's an extra level of complexity due to the different kinds of shifts, especially the _event_ shifts. Can I ask in particular what aspect of the scheduling is taking you the most time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a solution that works in Excel, I am going to say that this would be complicated. You might be able to use numerous worksheets and some vlookup commands to piece together a solution that meets some or many of your needs, but it would be very unlikely for it to know how to evenly distribute hours to employees.  In our current world of numerous public web applications, I suggested to you find an online application you can subscribe to that is made for employee scheduling.

https://www.google.com/search?q=employee+scheduling+app

Comment: thanks I will check this one out. I have looked at many of these and they haven't done what I need them to....